Dual to Eilenberg Watts
The Eilenberg-Watts theorem states:
Theorem. Let $A, B$ be rings and let $F : A\textbf{-Mod} \to B\textbf{-Mod}$ be a right exact, coproduct preserving additive functor. Then there
exists a unique (up to isomorphism) pair of an $B$-$A$ bimodule $P$ and a natural
isomorphism $F(-) \cong P \otimes_A -$.
Is the dual statement true? If not why? Specifically, a statement like:
Theorem? Let $A, B$ be rings and let $F : A\textbf{-Mod} \to B\textbf{-Mod}$ be a left exact, product preserving additive functor. Then there
exists a unique (up to isomorphism) pair of an $A$-$B$ bimodule $P$ and a natural
isomorphism $F(-) \cong \text{Hom}_A(P, -)$.

Yes, this is true, although it's more complicated to identify the bimodule than it is in the Eilenberg-Watts theorem.
It's a special case of Theorem VI.2.2 in Mitchell's Theory of Categories (1965), although Watts included the special case $B=\mathbb{Z}$ in the same 1960 paper in which he proved the Eilenberg-Watts theorem.
Briefly: It follows from general nonsense (e.g., the Special Adjoint Functor theorem) that $F$ has a left adjoint $G: B\textbf{-Mod} \to A\textbf{-Mod}$. By the Eilenberg-Watts theorem, $G$ is naturally isomorphic to $P\otimes_B-$ for some $A$-$B$ bimodule $P$, and so its right adjoint $F$ is naturally isomorphic to $\text{Hom}_A(P, -)$.

I see the E-W theorem talks about the form of Morita equivalences, and I know how practical Morita equivalence is.  This is probably a stupid question, but isn't an equivalence of module categories exact on both sides and preserving products and coproducts? Maybe it isn't, I'm not fluent with this.  Does E-W and its dual say two things about each equivalence of module categories, or is it actually describing two different things? If it's describing two different things, does anyone get any milage out of the dual version?

@rschwieb Both the Eilenberg-Watts theorem and its dual are more general than Morita equivalence, when they both apply (the functor is both left and right exact, and preserves both products and coproducts). And in that case, there is a $B$-$A$-bimodule $P$, the $A$-$B$-bimodules $Q=\text{Hom}_A(P,A)$ and $\text{Hom}_B(P,B)$ are isomorphic, and there are functors $P\otimes_A-\cong\text{Hom}_A(Q,-): A\textbf{-Mod} \to B\textbf{-Mod}$ and $\text{Hom}_B(P,-)\cong Q\otimes_B-:B\textbf{-Mod} \to A\textbf{-Mod}$ that are inverse equivalences of categories.

Thank you! That helps me put things in perspective quite nicely.
